Dell Latitute 7350 ('ultra 5) + webcam + Ubuntu 22.04
I've just bought a DELL Latitude 7350 (ultra 5) on which I've installed ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I'm having a problem with the webcam which isn't recognised... do you have any ideas please?
thank you

Try 24.04. Sometimes, later versions of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware.
